# Check for background audio playing and if so go to exact page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, navigation

I want after start application or activation to check if BackgroundAudioPlayer is playing and if so then go to page with player. I know that I couldn't use NavigationService and I found that in App.xaml.cs I should use RootVisual as in Activated but it's not working. RootVisual is null. The first one has no error but the problem is that I get to MainPage.xaml. So how can I fix it? Thanks

```
    private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayerState == PlayState.Playing)
            RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/PlayerPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }

    private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayerState == PlayState.Playing)
            (Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(new Uri("/PlayerPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
```

Comment: Hello Bibo, could you please let me know what is your default page in your application?

Answer (score 1):

I have amended your code, please have a look; it will work for you.

Remove your code form the Application_Activated event and put into Application_Launching Event. And do not write anything into Application_Activated.(in term of navigation context). Follow the two steps:

**STEP-1**
Go to *WMAppManifest.xml* file and remove "*MainPage.xaml*" entry from the default task. And keep empty entry of `NavigationPage`. like this `NavigationPage=""`

see the follwoing code snippet for the same.

```
<Tasks>
    <DefaultTask  Name ="_default" NavigationPage=""/>
  </Tasks>
  <Tokens>
    <PrimaryToken TokenID="liveTilesToken" TaskName="_default">
      <TemplateType5>
        <BackgroundImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Background.png</BackgroundImageURI>
        <Count>0</Count>
        <Title>liveTiles</Title>
      </TemplateType5>
    </PrimaryToken>
  </Tokens>
```

**STEP-2** Update code accordingly

```
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
        {
            Uri newUri = null;
            newUri = true ? new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative) : new Uri("/PlayerPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            RootFrame.Navigate(newUri);
        }
```

Hope it helps.

Thank you.

Comment: I get Error: Member 'YouRadio.App.RootFrame.get' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Comment: It's default App.xaml.cs created with Windows Phone 8 project. I think nothing special. I added to [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/pD38iRF0)

Comment: I have amended my code, in my previous answer, please check and let me know whether it helps for your case.

Comment: It's used like I show in my post but as I said. This didn't show any error but I get to MainPage.xaml (in my example I use PlayerPage so I don't want to MainPage).

Comment: I got your problem I thing you forget to remove entry form the WMAppManifest.xml in Tasks section, which you have to remove. Please have look I have updated code in my previous answer. And you have to manage page navigation Application_Launching event only. if your background player is not working then you have put the code snippet in the else part to navigate MainPage.xaml